# SQL Index: Increases performance when added manually, but scripted does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, indexing

Using MSSQL and MSSQL Server Management Studio, I have a fairly complex query with some joins and a couple of SubQueries.

One property that is selected is a decimal(19,5) named Duration. When using NHibernate's Queryover to grab this column in a SelectSubQuery, it takes around 2 minutes to hydrate my objects for some reason, the query is only a handful of milliseconds.

Adding an Index manually, Right Click Indexes -> Add Index, on (Id, Duration) makes the query slightly quicker, and hydration acceptable, not flawless, but good enough. However, if I Right Click the index -> Script Index as, and run that created script, it doesn't increase the performance of the query.

`Script Index As` creates

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Duration] ON [Table] 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Duration] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So what I can tell, manually created index increases performance, scripted index does not.

Comment: Does the execution plan of the query changes in the two cases? Did you try to re-compute the statistics?

Comment: Statements like "Right Click Indexes" etc. are just about meaningless since you haven't mentioned what tool this is from, or even what database system.

Comment: Something doesn't quite add up here... If NHibernate generates a single SQL query, and that exact same query takes only a few milliseconds when executed directly, then the hydration time should not be affected by creating an index. Do you perhaps have some SELECT N+1 issue during object hydration?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? Tags don't tell.

Comment: The syntax looks like MSSQL. I would think that the execution plan has been cached. Read about the consequences of running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, then run it if it's appropriate. If it's not the plan, then perhaps NHibernate is setting some weird options that prevent SQL Server from using the index from NHibernate's session.

Comment: My apologies, MSSQL and MSSQL Server Management Studio are what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

The same code in Management studio is used to generate the SQL when you create the index using the designer, or right-clicking and scripting the object.  (Both use SMO - Sql Management Objects library).  You can verify that they are identical by using Profiler to capture the sql statements SSMS generates.